# AWS API Gateway + Lambda Proxy Integration Cache Issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to set-up API Gateway + Lambda Proxy + Cache and having issues with it.

Firstly it doesn't seem to be hitting the cache. Oddly when I use chrome dev tools to hit it and click 'disable' cache, it somehow does hit the cache! The difference is it sets the cache-control to 'none'. A normal requests it sets cache-control to 'max-age=0'.

Secondly when it does cache, its ignoring the URL parameter as a key so with different querystring values, it still returns the same response.

I have enabled the API Cache on the stage settings, I have also entered the 'querystrings' in the Method request settings as well and turned on the 'caching' checkbox for each querystring parameter.

Any thoughts on this? If this does not work I may have to resort to using Elasticache internally but it would have been great if API Gateway could handle this directly.

My API request are 'GET' requests with querystring parameters.

Comment: How are you determining if caching is working? The cache does take some time to provision and in some scenarios you may get a false cache hit or miss if the cache is not ready.

Comment: Currently I am basing it on the response time, without cache it takes about 3-5 seconds. With cache it goes to 100ms.

Comment: Response time is not going to be a good indicator, too many variables involved (for instance TLS between CloudFront and API Gateway). You should actually look at the published CacheHit metrics in CloudWatch.